# alert not displayed after using document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, alert

I am not very skilled when it comes to frontend stuff so maybe I am overlooking something obvious here.
I have an input form and when clicking submit the code below sends the data to a java backend which tries to save that data. If it succeeds it responds with 200, if something's wrong with the data it responds with 400. I tried adding alerts which tell the user if it succeeded or not. These work unless I try to validate the input before sending it:

```
function saveEntry() {

  var form = document.getElementById("catalogEntry");  // apparently this line breaks all alerts within the ajax call
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      form.classList.add("was-validated");
      return;
  }

  var formData = new FormData();
  // *Appending form data*

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/addCatalogEntry/",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      timeout: 600000,
      statusCode: {
          200: function (response) {
              alert("Entry saved");
          },
          400: function (response) {
              alert("Could not save entry");
          }
    }
  });

}
```

If I remove the first 5 lines in the function the alerts are displayed but then there's no input validation. As soon as I add the line where I initialize the form variable alerts stop showing up. I managed to bring them up again by adding another pointless alert after the ajax call. I am really confused to why this is happening...

If important, my form looks basically like this:

```
<form id="catalogEntry">

  <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-2">catalogId</span>
    <input id="catalogId" type="text" class="form-control" required>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <span class="input-group-addon col-sm-2">blockType</span>
    <select id="blockType" class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="saveEntry()">Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I do not see you cancelling the form submission...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `getElementById` line.  That comment is incorrect.  The error is not originating from that line, directly.

Comment: I think you need to use something like `event.preventDefault();` https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Since you are doing ajax, if you don't want the form to submit, change your button to be `type="button"` rather than submit.

Comment: I'm sure if you just [stepped though your code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) the problem would become obvious pretty quickly.

Comment: @Taplar that actually fixed it. I don't really understand why though. I guess I should read the documentation about button types tomorrow..

Comment: If your form submits, the page is going to do a page transfer, and the ajax could potentially not happen/be cancelled.  Returning from the method doesn't cancel the form submit, as your function call is on the "click" of the button, not on the submit of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing

```
return; // returns "undefined"
```

inside your form check, the rest of the code doesn't get executed.

Comment: I think that's on purpose. The OP checks if the form is valid before doing this

Comment: @Liam It also means that in case  `checkValidity()` returns `false` the AJAX call never happens, and thus, no alert.

Comment: @Liam is right, that is on purpose. However if checkValidity() returns true I didn't see any alerts

Answer (score -1):

inside a function you can't use a `return` key if you want to continue the script, in your case when the code is read and the `if` sentence is `true` (`form.checkValidity() === false`) you break the code with the `return`

Comment: Isn't this basically [identical to this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52723880/542251)